# Execute a single task with multiple threads on a schedule

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a function `foo()` that I want to be invoked by multiple threads on an interval. example: want to execute foo() every 100ms with x number of threads. I am unsure how to go about it.

I am looking at [FixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) where you can instantiate a thread pool with number of workers. However when you invoke using this thread pool does it exhaust all threads at once and executes a task?

any ideas would be appreciated; thanks

Comment: Why do you need multiple threads for a single repeating task?

Answer (score 0):

For a single task being repeated, you do not need multiple threads.

Use a single-threaded [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Define your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`.

```
Runnable task = … ;
```

Schedule for repeated execution.

```
ScheduledFuture future = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( task , 0 , 100 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) ;
```

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Sure, but the function would be polling from a queue and I want multiple invocations of that to happen per interval, per instance. Currently it's using new single threaded scheduled executor but was wondering if I could add more threads.

Comment: @kt-workflow You need to edit your Question to explain your situation in detail. Both your Question and your Comment are unclear.

Comment: sure.. basically just meant I want this function to be multiple times on an interval. a single threaded scheduled executor would only execute the function once per interval right. is there an easier way to execute the function multiple times on an interval without instantiated multiple ScheduledExecutorServices